# Perl regex logic error

Tags: perl, logic

I'm rather new to the concept of Regex. I understand basic regex I use in bash script. The following snippet of code is from a program I'm writing to automatically update Wordpress plugins on the server.

Anyway the concept is that this piece of code is part of a subroutine which recurses through .php files in a directory, and tries to pattern match files starting with "Version:", "version:", "*Version:" etc from the file, and if pattern is matched, another sub then tries to extract the value following the character ":" to get the correct version number.

```
$searchpath=$path."/".$plugins[$i];
        @files = <$searchpath/*.php>;
        print "Search path is ".$searchpath."\n";
OUT:    foreach $file (@files) 
        {
            print "Checking alternate php file: ".$file."\n";
            open(txt, $file);
            while($line = <txt>) 
            {
                for ($line)
                {
                 s/^\s+//;
                 s/\s+$//;
                }
                if ( $line =~ /^Version:|^version:|^\* Version:|\sVersion:/ )
                {
                    print "Version found in file ".$file."\n";  
                    $varfound=1;    
                    close(txt);
                    $ver=&read_extract($file);
                    print $ver."\n";
                    $pluginversion[$i]=$ver;
                    print "Array Num ".$i." Stored plugin name:".$plugins[$i]." Version found ".$ver." Version stored ".$pluginversion[$i]."\n";
                    last OUT;
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is that I seem to be having an error in logic, and the file actually matches " . phpversion() . "\n"; Version stored " . phpversion() . "\n" for the search query. With my limited knowledge I find it difficult to understand what's wrong, and would be eager for some advice.

The other subs referred to are included below:

```
sub read_extract
{
    my $pl_version="";
    open(txt, my $file=$_[0]);
    while($line = <txt>)
    {
        for ($line)
        {
         s/^\s+//;
         s/\s+$//;
        }           
        if ( $line =~ /^Version:|^version:|^\* Version:|\sVersion:/ )
        {
            $pl_version=&extract_version($line);
        }
    }
    close(txt);
    $pl_version;
}

sub extract_version
{
    my $line=$_[0];
    $string=substr($line,rindex($line, ":")+1);
    for ($string)
    {
     s/^\s+//;
     s/\s+$//;
    }
    $string;
}
```

If my subroutine is required in full, I can include it. However my debug lines show this:

```
Processing xcloner-backup-and-restore...Search path is /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/admin.cloner.html.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/admin.cloner.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/admin.xcloner-backupandrestore.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/admin.xcloner.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/cloner.config.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/cloner.cron.php
Checking alternate php file: /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/cloner.functions.php
Version found in file /var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/vettathu.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/cloner.functions.php
" . phpversion() . "\n";
Array Num 26 Stored plugin name:xcloner-backup-and-restore Version found " . phpversion() . "\n"; Version stored " . phpversion() . "\n";
```

which seems to be where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a lot of redundant code there. If you have the line already, why do you need to close the file and find the line again? All you need to do is capture the string when you find the line:

```
if ( $line =~ /^\*?\s?Version:(.*)/i ) {
    my $version = $1;
```

So, by using the `/i` modifier, your match is case insensitive. By placing `?` after `\*` and `\s` they can match 0 or 1 time. By using `(.*)` the rest of the line is captured to `$1`.

Your regex was lacking a `^` beginning of line anchor in the last match, which I assumed was a typo. If not, you can simply change the regex to `/\bVersion:(.*)/i`. And the `\b` is only useful for avoiding partial matches, such as `subversion: foo`.

Comment: Wouldnt the \* mean the expression matches only if it begins with * ? I guess I have to modify it to include other OR like `/^\s?Version:(.*)/` Would the /i work even if I have OR like `$line =~ /^\*?\s?Version:(.*)|^\s?Version:(.*)/i`  ?

Comment: I don't know what "to include other or like" means, but no, `\*?` means "match a literal * 0 or 1 time". You could also do `[*\s]*` to make all such characters optional.

Comment: @Droidzone No... that's not it. `*` being optional means it doesn't have to be there... so `\*?\s?|\s?` means exactly the same as `\*?\s?`.

Comment: For example, `a?b?` would match both `ab` and `b`, so `a?b?|b?` would be redundant.

Comment: Thank you. But I confess that I'm still confused. It was my understanding that the expression is read from left to right. So in the expression `/^\*?\s?Version:(.*)/`, it means look for a string beginning with a literal * followed by 1 or 0 matches of a whitespace, followed by literal "Version:" followed by any or zero repetitions of any character. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: The question mark `?` after the star `\*` makes it optional (match 0 or 1 time). In exactly the same way that `\s?` means the whitespace is optional (match 0 or 1 time). I don't quite understand why you understand it about the whitespace but not about the star. :)

Comment: That's because I was reading it from left to right! There's a ? before \s, so I thought that goes with \s. I get it now. I know that .* means match 0 or any characters of . (any character). It's analogous. Thanks a lot for explaining in depth!

Comment: @Droidzone You're welcome. And yes, quantifiers are applied to whatever is before them. As a bonus, I will also confuse you further by explaining that `?` is equivalent to `{0,1}`, `+` means `{1,}` and `*` means `{0,}`. ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27269/discussion-between-droidzone-and-tlp)